# React-Redux: Can't use store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new in React. And I'm studying Redux now. I understand how the library works, but I completely don’t understand why my code doesn't. The problem is: 
**React doesn't see the store**. I can't use datas from the store.

store.js:

```
   import {createStore} from "redux";
    import reducer from "./reducers/reducer";

    const initialState = {
      notes: [
        {
          name: "First note",
        },
        {
          name: "Second note",
        },
      ]
    };

   const store = createStore(reducer, initialState)
   export default store;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from "./store";
import App from './containers/App.js';

ReactDOM.render(
    (<Provider store={store}>
      <App />,
    </Provider>),
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import MainContainer from "./MainContainer";
// import {connect} from "react-redux";
function App() {
  return (
   <div className="App">
     <MainContainer />
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MainContainer.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

function MainContainer(props) {
  return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <ul>
          {props.notes.map(note => <li key={note.name}>{note.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  notes: state.notes
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainContainer)
```

reducer.js:

```
import uuid from 'react-uuid';

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === 'CREATE_NOTE') {
    return ({
          notes: [
            ...this.state.notes,
            {
              key: uuid(),
              id: uuid(),
              name: action.input,
              detail: action.inputTextArea,
            }
          ]
        }
    )
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

I tried to use connect() but had the same result.

Thanks in advance for yours help.

**Thanks to all! I mistaked in reducer. I just realized that I did not return state**

Comment: You have no store.

Comment: Checkout the demo of redux + react provided by microsoft [here](https://github.com/microsoft/frontend-bootcamp) and official document [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started), it seems there are many things need to be done from your current code.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the data in your store?

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry. I edited code from the phone and accidentally deleted part of the code. Already fixed

Comment: @Nick MainContainer

Comment: Can you most your MainContainer code? that's where you'd (probably) connect to redux

Comment: How are you *using* the store? We can’t diagnose what we can’t see.

Comment: I added MainContainer.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store seems to be missing in the code that you provided. Try this:

```
import {createStore} from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducers/reducer";

const initialState = {
   notes: [
      {
         name: "First note",
      },
      {
         name: "Second note",
      },
   ]
};


const store = createStore(
     reducer,
     initialState
)

export default store
```

Now to access your store, you can `useSelector` or `connect` from the `react-redux` library

// Using  useSelector

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
const notes = useSelector(state => state.notes)
```

// Using connect

You first need to importe `connect` from `react-redux` like this:

`import {connect} from 'react-redux'`

and use it like this

```
const MyAwesomeComponent = (props)=> (
   props.notes.map(note => <li key={note.name}>{note.name}</li>)
)

const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
   const { notes } = state
   return notes
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyAwesomeComponent)
```

Remember to check out the [the react-redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start)

Comment: Thanks. But I tried this method, but still does not work. Attached MainContainer to the topic header

Comment: I used MyAwesomeComponent  as an example. You can replace it with it whatever your component name is

Comment: What are getting? Can you share your code? We can’t help you if you don’t share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could connect `MainContainer` to your redux state.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const MainContainer = props => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.notes.map(note => <li key={note.name}>{note.name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  ); 
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  notes: state.notes
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainContainer);
```

Comment: I tried this method, but still does not work. Attached MainContainer to the topic header